# How can we redirect the jsf error messages from a JSF Converter to a Text Area backed by a Backing Bean

Tags: jsf, textarea, converters, message

How to show the jsf error messages from a JSF Converter in a Text Area instead of `h:message`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have a custom Zip Code converter which throws a error message . So the ValueChangeListener do not get fired. If it did , I could capture it there and then show it in text area. Is there a way to get this errormessage in the bean on an onchange event so that I can display in a text area instead of h:messages? I do not want to use a PhaseListener here

Comment: Edit your question and add the relevant information there, not as a comment

Comment: Has anyone tried to show JSF validation,conversion errors in a Text Area box on the screen